# User location not found :- latitude and longitude in android

Tags: java, android

My code putput always goes in else part. IT means {location} is null.

Any suggestions?

```
locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, locationListener);  
location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if(location != null)                                
            {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            }  else {
                // 
            }
.....
.....
....
```

Comment: from where you can send the lat/lng value to the emulator? you have send the value by selecting the device from the devicelist and be sure your gps was enable in emulator

Comment: I am tesing on real device with debug development on.

Answer (score 1):

If locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) returns null then it means you have never been located.

If you want to get the new location, you should make you activity extend the LocationListener interface and implement the following.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Code to execute after being located
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}
```

Don't forget to remove the location updates afterwards.

Comment: Yes , I foreget to implement Listener. Now code working fine. Thanks

Comment: Can you accept the answer as correct, please? It would be the right way to do things ;).

Comment: Thaks Tiago I fixed with your coordination